# AS3 - What does DisplayObject() Really do? And why do I have to use it?

Tags: actionscript-3

I recently came across a problem which was

```
parent.addChild(example);
```

And got an error:

```
1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

The solution was

```
parent.addChild(DisplayObject(example));
```

What is DisplayObject doing that addChild is not? I thought addChild controls whether or not a movieclip is visible? I realize I shouldn't use parent.addChild, and will clean up the code so it's not needed, but I would still like to know what addChild purpose is and what DisplayObject does.

I read the help files to try to find out when you use DisplayObject, but only could find the definition. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide all your code that's related to `example`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is `DisplayObject` doing that `addChild` is not?

You are comparing apples and oranges with that question. The first one is a type (or class) and the second one is a method.

[Take a look at the signature of addChild() method as found in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29):

```
public function addChild(child:DisplayObject):DisplayObject
```

The parameter that you pass to the method must be of type `DisplayObject`.
But you are passing it an `Object`, which is what the error is complaining about.

Your question should be:

> What is `DisplayObject` doing that `Object` is not?

And the answer is: it can be passed as a parameter to `addChild`, whereas `Object` cannot be passed.

Whatever `example` is, it is typed to `Object`.

Due to how types work, `example` could hold a value of pretty much any type, because `Object` is the super type of them all. That means that `example` **could** be a `DisplayObject` indeed. But the compiler can't tell for sure. It is typed to `Object`, so again it could be everything else.

You need to make it clear that it is in fact a `DisplayObject`, which you do by casting to that type.

---

> Last thing does: `var example:Example = new Example; addChild(example);` work because it extends `MovieClip` and assumes it's an `Object`?

The `extends` relationship between classes can be mentally substituted for a `is` relationship. So if

```
Something extends SomethingElse
```

that means `Something` *is* `SomethingElse`. Think of this as `Something` being a more specialised version of `SomethingElse`. Here's another real world example:

```
Chair extends Furniture
```

Every chair is furniture. (but not every furniture is a chair!)

If

```
Example extends MovieClip
```

`Example` *is* a `MovieClip`. From the documentation you can see that

```
MovieClip extends Sprite
Sprite extends DisplayObjectContainer
DisplayObjectContainer extends InteractiveObject
InteractiveObject extends DisplayObject
```

which means that `Example` *is* a `DisplayObject`. You can find the full inheritance chain up to `Object` on every class in the documentation on the top of the page, for [`MovieClip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) it looks like this:

```
MovieClip -> Sprite -> DisplayObjectContainer -> InteractiveObject -> DisplayObject -> EventDispatcher -> Object
```

adding your `Example` class it looks like this:

```
Example -> MovieClip -> Sprite -> DisplayObjectContainer -> InteractiveObject -> DisplayObject -> EventDispatcher -> Object
```

As you can see, your `Example` *is* a bunch of stuff. Yes, it also is an `Object`, but that's doesn't really matter here. All that `addChild()` cares about that it *is* a `DisplayObject`.

One last thing: You can also do this, because `Example` *is* an `Object`

```
var example:Object = new Example;
```

but then this line will fail again:

```
addChild(example);
```

because the variable is typed to `Object` and that's what matters to the compiler. You have to go down the inheritance chain from `Object` down to at least `DisplayObject`. But most likely you want to type your variable to `Example` as you did in your question, because you usually create a class to add more functionality to the object. If you define that functionality (say some methods for example) in a class, then you want to type your variable to that class in order to use it.

Comment: Ok this clears it up. Thanks for the detailed answer. Last thing does: var example:Example = new Example; addChild(example); Work because it extends MovieClip and assumes it's an object?

Comment: @Beckley Yes, `MovieClip` extends `DisplayObject` through several other classes, therefore it can appear wherever a `DisplayObject` is required.

Comment: @Beckley Vesper is right, I edited my answer to clarify your question.

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to explain it, I can say with complete confidence that I understand what both do now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the concept wrong. The error message you get is saying to you, that the method `addChild()` expects to get parameter of type `DisplayObject` (or one of its descendants), but instead, you passed just generic `Object`. 
The syntax `DisplayObject(example)` tells flash to cast (convert) `example` to `DisplayObject`.

More about type conversion in AS3: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html

Comment: Oh okay, this makes sense. As I was making example = anotherObject. One last thing, how come var example:Example = new Example, addChild(Example) works, but                                                       anotherObject = Example addChild(anotherObject) doesn't?

Comment: It depends on the type of anotherObejct. If you have `anotherObject:Object = example`, than the assigning will work (because Object is super type for every type), but calling addChild(anotherObject) will fail, because you can't add generic Object to display list.
But if you have `anotherObject:DisplayObject = example` (assuming that example's type is descendant of DisplayObject), you can call `addChild(anotherObject)`, because anotherObject is now DisplayObject

Answer (score 0):

DisplayObject is simply the base class of all Objects that can be added to a display list and displayed on screen. By making sure only a DisplayObject can be used with addChild the system makes sure a valid object is added to the display list. Trying to add any object type that is not a subclass of DisplayObject will correctly fail. Unlike said in kejmi answer, all ancestor of DisplayObject class will fail, only descendants can be added.

Comment: you are right, I meant descendants, I'll edit my answer